# Detemine directory path of originating URL for Ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, linux, http, symlink

I have a ajax request to https://foo.bar.example.com/lib/foo/bar/ajax.php?

`/var/www/html/lib/` is a symbolic link to `/var/www/application/lib/`.

Within `/var/www/application/lib/foo/bar/ajax.php`, I need to determine whether the original page where the ajax request originated from had one of the following three directory paths:

1. `/lib/someSpecificFile.php` (i.e. https://foo.bar.example.com/lib/someSpecificFile.php?a=b)
2. `/someSpecificDirectory/index.php` (i.e. https://foo.bar.example.com/someSpecificDirectory/index.php?a=b or https://foo.bar.example.com/someSpecificDirectory/)
3. Any other path.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: @Barbar.  I was contemplating using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.  So just manipulate it by removing the protocol based on `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` and the host based on  `$_SERVER['HOST']`, and any trailing GET data, and then use a `switch` statement or if/else?

Comment: Looks like `parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])` might be a better choice.